# file already exists error csom office 365

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, csom

I use the below code

```
 FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
            newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            newFile.Url = fileName;
 Folder folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderName);
                uploadFile = folder.Files.Add(newFile);
```

This works fine when the file is already not present, but throws error when file exists already

How can I update the file instead of adding if its existing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overwrite file if it already exists by setting `Overwrite` equal true.

```
 newFile.Overwrite = true;
```

Find more in *MSDN* [FileCreationInformation.Overwrite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.filecreationinformation.overwrite.aspx)

## Modified Code

```
FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
            newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            newFile.Url = fileName;
            newFile.Overwrite = true;
 Folder folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderName);
                uploadFile = folder.Files.Add(newFile);
```

Comment: Thank you Atish. Upvoted and accepted answer
also, if you can suggest some blogs for learning sharepoint, it would be very helpful

Comment: What you want to learn? I have some articles on REST API http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/MemberArticles.aspx?amid=11468596

Comment: Please check this question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198627/