# assign webpart to a group using dwp file

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, office-365, 2016

I have a dwp file

I want to assign it to an already existing group instead of miscellaneous group

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebPart xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
  <Title>MY WEBPART</Title>
  <FrameType>None</FrameType>
  <Description>some description</Description>
  <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>
  <ZoneID>xa63fb0bf942d61798f0e24</ZoneID>
  <PartOrder>0</PartOrder>
  <Group>MY GROUP NAME</Group>
..some other properties..
</Webpart>
```

If i upload this dwp file, but its not coming under "MY GROUP NAME" 
How should it be done?

Comment: In which group it's showing?

Comment: its showing up under miscellaneous